# Marking a whole <li> to be clickable

Tags: html

I have a list with options like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="somewhere">Somewhere</a></li>
<li><a href="A">A</a></li>
<li><a href="B">B</a></li>
<li><a href="C">C</a></li>
</ul>
```

However only the letters are clickable so I tried this:

```
   <a href="somewhere"><li>somewhere</li></a>
```

Now the whole li is clickable as desired but JetBrains tell me that the element is not allowed there. Is there a proper way to do this?

This doesn't have anything to do with Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your CSS so that the entire area is covered by the `<a>`.

You probably want `display: block`.